# Why is emacs not preinstalled?

Tags: emacs, vi

I want to learn Emacs or Vi. I don't like modal editing but Vi is ubiquitous and looks more useful for emergencies. What are the reasons why Emacs is not preinstalled in most distributions?

Comment: It should be easy enough to install it yourself.

Comment: Obviously, because it is inferior to the ONE TRUE EDITOR... And also because it is not part of the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/stage7tc1/utilities/vi.html).

Comment: Vi was written for BSD Unix as has been around since the 70s; GNU Emacs was written for the GNU project, and has been around since the 80s. Vi is seen as a standard Unix system utility, while emacs is more of an add on application.

Comment: licensing. From `man sh` in [**Rationale**:](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sh.html) *The community of `emacs` proponents was adamant that the full `emacs` editor not be standardized because they were concerned that an attempt to standardize this very powerful environment would encourage vendors to ship strictly conforming versions lacking the extensibility required by the community.*

Comment: Because there are many people who don't like emacs (I regard it as an example of how to build the worst possible editor that still works :-)), so why consume disk space?  Of course this also begs the questions: 1) Why isn't my preferred editor installed by default? and 2) Why isn't there a way to remove all the other stuff I'll never use, such as error messages in languages I don't read?

Comment: @jamesqf - of course you can remove languages you don't read. Your comment is why I just changed my mind and decided to vote to close after all. And if you're talking about `emacs` error messages in particular *(which I know nothing about because I don't use it)* I would be very surprised to learn it didn't use GNU gettext and you can't just strip that stuff at compile time like you can for any other package.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The direct answer is probably that `vi` is part of the POSIX standard (as @jasonwryan also mentioned in a comment), as well as the Single UNIX Specification. As such, anything that calls itself POSIX-compliant probably includes something `vi`-like, and anything that wants to call itself UNIX *has* to, or you don't get certified. Not just `vi`, but the related line editor `ex` and the scripting language involved are also part of these standards. `emacs` is not part of the standard, so it is not included.

As for *why* this is so, there are several reasons. For one, `emacs` is far, far bigger and more complicated than `vi`. There's a whole LISP in there, among other things. The part of POSIX that decides this was written in 1992, when you would need a very beefy computer for `emacs`. I've seen a `vi` run on Minix on a 286 semi-decently. And while it doesn't really matter all that much for a modern desktop, on embedded systems it still very much does. Its size and versatility also makes it harder to check it for security holes, which might be an issue in certain applications where security is imperative. Basically, everything that might make it a better desktop application makes it a worse system component.

If you're up for a history lesson, you could also say that `vi` is closer to the [Unix philosophy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy): *do one thing and do it well*. Indeed, `vi` sprang from `ex`, and has always been an Unix program. `emacs` sprang from a vastly different world: it was originally built on top of TECO, written for the [ITS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incompatible_Timesharing_System) operating system. It was only ported to Unix in the 1980s, as ITS was dying out. This makes `emacs` in effect an immigrant from a very different culture, while `vi` is a native.

Interestingly, both `emacs` and `vi` first came out in 1976, so it's not just that `vi` is older.

Comment: "This makes emacs in effect an immigrant from a very different culture, while vi is a native." Beautifully put. +1

Comment: It is probably no longer the case that "emacs is far, far bigger and more complicated than vi.", at least in the current most popular incarnation of `vi`, namely `vim`. There is currently an entire SE site devoted solely to `vi` and its avatars, including `vim`.

Comment: @FaheemMitha: `vim` is still a lot smaller than `emacs`. At least the ones you get from Debian's repository, the `emacs` executable is five times as large as the `vim` one. It also has more dependencies. But that's just one particular implementation. There's a serviceable `vi` in BusyBox, you can find it running on modems and such. It's not very full-featured, but it is obviously still `vi`. You could not do that with `emacs` and still call it `emacs`.

Comment: @marinus good points.

Comment: My question was put on hold as primarily opinion-based. I think it's not opinion-based and you proved it giving an objective and complete answer :)

Comment: @marinus: The BusyBox in `vi` is most definitely "serviceable": I use it  as my primary text editor for most usecases, and that includes a lot of writing software too. Generally with more of the optional features-turned-on at BusyBox compilation, granted, but still. I started my Linux system-admin and software-development skillset growth on a phone with busybox, so I got used to it, and don't find myself missing all the features that I never got used to having. (It goes without saying, I'm an unabashedly weird person.)

Answer (score 1):

This is not how it works.

The choice of packages installed by default is typically driven by practical needs. There is no single practical reason to add particularly emacs into a default installation, unless you are installing a distribution specifically focused on emacs users, if there is anything like that at all.

A typical linux distribution by default installs a minimal system plus what the userbase is expected to use (very often a graphical desktop, firefox, libreoffice and a couple of tools). If emacs is not part of the minimal system, it doesn't make sense to have it in the default installation.

A minimal system is there to allow a power user (administrator) to run the system, perform basic configuration tasks using the command line, and install whatever he wants.

There is certainly need for a text editor in such a minimal system, as you may need to edit configuration files. A good minimal candidate is *nano* as it's both easy to use and very small in footprint, therefore you will find it in minimal systems of most distributions nowadays. Another good candidate is a simple implementation of *vi* because, as others mentioned, it's the standard editor on POSIX systems. That is why minimal systems typically contain those two, sometimes only one of them.

An entirely wrong choice would be *emacs* which is not minimal, not easy to use as nano and not standard as vi. Another rather poor choice would be a full installation of *vim*. Those are tools that belong to full installations ranging from your complete home setup with your favourite editor to university setups for shared computers with a choice of installed tools for a wide range of users.